# How can I find $\gcd(n^a-1,m^a-1)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

From [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1) , we have $$\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$$
for every positive integers $a,n,m$.

I reversed $a$ with $n,m$, and I had this question:

> Find $\gcd(n^a-1,m^a-1)$ for every positive integers $a,n,m$

My attempt is to find the greatest common divisor of $n^p-1$ and $m^p-1$ for every prime $p$ such that $p|a$, but I couldn't get any further.

How can I find the general formula of $\gcd(n^a-1,m^a-1)$ ?

(sorry for my grammar mistake, English is my second language)

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to expect a nice answer for $\gcd(n^a-1, m^a-1)$ in general. Of course if $a+1$ is prime and $n$ and $m$ are coprime to $a+1$, $a+1$ divides that gcd.